# How to execute program on Google Compute Engine locally

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

As the title, I have some programs already uploaded to the compute engine instance running Linux, and plan to execute them locally.

However, I can't find any doc in Google Compute Engine API that how to execute the program from my local.

For example, I am looking for a function like

```
instance.run_Command("$ sudo python program.py args")
```

Any idea? Using google-cloud-api is not necessary, any methods are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) in Python.  Behind the scenes Fabric just uses SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE --command 'python program.py args'`.